# How to access `.Range` object item by index?

Tags: excel, vba

Normally I would access `.Range` object item by index number like this:

```
debug.print Selection(2)
```

But I get

> Type mismatch

if I try this on the following, because `r.Count` is only 1:

```
For Each r In grouping_range.Rows
    Debug.Print r(1)
Next r
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cells in `r` are grouped by rows. Use `r.Cells(1)` to return the first cell in the group.